# If my question was closed, and I edited it, and there are a lot of answers, can I ask the answerers to vote to reopen?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

My question was closed, and there are a lot of answers. I have since edited the question.

Now can I ask the answerers to vote to reopen?

Comment: nothing is stopping you, though, such comments could easily be flagged away as "no longer needed". personally i wouldn't want to receive such a comment.

Answer (score 5):

It's good that you edited [the question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571421/77072) (I assume it's that one) to improve it; this had put the question into the [Reopen Votes review queue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/stats), where [three users voted to leave it closed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/309697).

Since you already received six answers, is it *that* important that it's reopened *quickly*, important enough to use comments (again, I assume you want to use comments for this) for something other than [their intended purpose](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) (i.e. to help improving the answer)? Your question can still be reopened by users browsing the site, stumbling upon your question and voting to reopen it.

Answer (score 4):

Asking the post authors of the answers to [your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571421) to vote to reopen isn't necessarily the best course of action here.

You've edited your question, which kicked it into the Reopen Votes review queue, however it appears this had a [Leave Closed outcome](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/309697). It might simply be best to accept that this question might, indeed, need to be closed per your site's  content and quality standards.

If you feel as though this is in error, and have an understandable reason as to why, raise your point of concern on that site's [Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/). Be sure to include your reason as to why the post should be reopened. Users may ask you to make further edits to consider it reopen-able, so be sure to consider their input.